# How to write MVC2 Validation For this

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code in my view page.

```
<td>
                        Mandate Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= Html.TextBox("MandateName")%>
                    </td>
```

I wrote MVC2 Validation for this name.

something like this.

```
//[Validator(typeof(MandateValidator))]
    [MetadataType(typeof(Mandate_Metadata))]
    public partial class Mandate {

        public class Mandate_Metadata
        {
            [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Mandate name cannot exceed 250 characters!")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mandate Name Required!")]
            public string MandateName { get; set; }

            [StringLength(3000, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot exceed 3000 characters!")]
            public string MandateDescription { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

but some how my validation is not working on this field could any body help me what's wrong I am doing here?
thanks

Comment: More info please. Is it the client side validation or server side validation that isn't working? If it's client side, please let us know what you're using there. If it's server side, please show us your action method code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have anything like

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MandateName)%>
```

in your view?

Check out SottGu's [post on Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) with mvc2.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since I have played with MVC, however,  I'm fairly certain you are missing your validation message..  IE something like

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.MandateName) %>
```

Also cited at the top of your form inside of your using statement, you need

```
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
```